# How can I list running windows services ordered by Start time by PowerShell?

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, service

How can I list all the running services as a list ordered by the Started time in descending ordey, by using Powershell ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What have you tried? You should come quite far using [`Get-Service`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176858.aspx) and [`Sort-Object`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176968.aspx).

Edit: `Get-Service` doesn't do start time, but there is a [workaround](http://techibee.com/powershell/powershell-query-windows-service-start-time/1336):

```
[cmdletbinding()]            

param (
 [parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
 [string[]]$ComputerName = $env:computername,            

 [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
 [Alias("ServiceName")]
 [string]$Name            

)            

begin{}            

Process {            

 foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName) {
  if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -Count 1 -ea 0) {
   Write-Verbose "$Computer is online"
   $Service = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $Computer -Filter "Name='$Name'" -ea 0
   if($Service) {
    $ServicePID = $Service.ProcessID
    $ProcessInfo = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -ComputerName $Computer -Filter "ProcessID='$ServicePID'" -ea 0
    $OutputObj  = New-Object -Type PSObject
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ComputerName -Value $Computer.ToUpper()
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $Name
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DisplayName -Value $Service.DisplayName
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name StartTime -Value $($Service.ConvertToDateTime($ProcessInfo.CreationDate))
    $OutputObj
   } else {
    write-verbose "Service `($Name`) not found on $Computer"
   }
  } else {
   write-Verbose "$Computer is offline"
  }
 }            

}            

end {}
```

Comment: Changing the line below can allow you to do a wildcard search of the service name:  $Service = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $Computer -Filter "Name='$Name'" -ea 0  to $Service = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $Computer -Filter "Name LIKE '%$Name%'" -ea 0